# can I mount a copper pipe to stone with an epoxy?

Tags: copper, copper-tubing

how can I mount a copper pipe vertically to a flat slate stone after first drilling into the stone to insert the end of the copper tubing?

Comment: Much more detail is required. Please include length of copper pipe, diameter of the copper pipe, thickness of the flat slate stone, how deep the hole is in the flat slate slab, how big/heavy is the slate stone and what is the diameter of the hole drilled into the slate slab.

Comment: It will also be necessary to understand the usage model of the copper pipe mounted into the stone in this manner. Decorative usage could have very different performance requirements from structural usage.

Comment: I agree mor information would be helpful but a good epoxy like gorilla glue would hold copper to stone

Comment: Copper oxidizes and many glues/epoxies have difficulty adhering to copper long-term. Look for a glue made for copper, and clean the copper well before gluing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can. In fact, this is exactly how anchor bolts are placed into concrete and stone for posts. A hole is drilled, filled with epoxy, then the bolt is inserted.

Keep in mind that slate is fragile, however. Go easy on the drill so as to not crack the slate.